# check if certain textboxes are empty

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, textbox, string

ok, I needed to check if only 4 out of 15 textboxes were empty, but with no luck. I tried:

```
if txtbox1.text = "" then
lblerror1.visible=true
exitsub
else
bla bla
end if
```

But that left error text and didn't see the user entering the text in the textbox, so I looked and found string.isnullorwhitespace(string.value)...
well, that didn't tell me how to use it so I searched more and found this:
if string.isnullorwhitespace(textbox.text) then..

well that was it and here is the outcome. now if I could only get a for-next or do -while to only chaeck the 4 text fileds I need to check and not all textboxes.

ASPX page code:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblerror" runat="server" Text="Page error" Visible="false" forecolor="red"/><br />
<asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" Width="100px" /><asp:Label ID="nameblankerror" runat='server' Text="cannot be blank" ForeColor="Red" Visible="false" /><br />
<asp:TextBox ID="txtcompname" runat="server" Width="100px" /><asp:Label ID="compblankerror" runat='server' Text="cannot be blank" ForeColor="Red" Visible="false" /><br />
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="submit" /><br />
<asp:Label ID="lbl1" runat="server" Visible="true" Text="TextBox 1: " /><asp:label ID="lblname" runat="server" /><br />
<asp:Label ID="lbl2" runat="server" Visible="true" Text="TextBox 2: " /><asp:label ID="lblCompName" runat="server" />
```

and for the backend code:

```
    Protected Sub btnSubmit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSubmit.Click
    'test to see if certain the fields are blank
    Dim str1 As String = txtName.Text
    Dim str2 As String = txtcompname.Text
    Dim CatchMe As Integer = 0

    If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtName.Text) Then
        nameblankerror.Visible = True
        CatchMe += 1
    Else
        nameblankerror.Visible = False
        lblname.text = str1.Trim()
        CatchMe += 0
    End If
    If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtcompname.Text) Then
        compblankerror.Visible = True
        CatchMe += 1
    Else
        compblankerror.Visible = False
        lblCompName.Text = str2.Trim()
        CatchMe += 0
    End If
    If CatchMe = 0 Then
        'do something like process SQL Command
        lblerror.Visible = False
        Exit Sub
    ElseIf CatchMe <> 0 Then
        'return to page and process nothing
        lblerror.Visible = True
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub
```

so that is it. a simple, easy to follow check for certain textboxes out of a bunch.
Like I stated above if I could figure out how to check only certain textboxes and not all textboxes, that and make the code shorter would be great. I put in a catchme so that if one box was filled in it wouldn't show the user that they need to fill that one also (in Error), but would catch the other empty textboxes.
to make it clear, if I have 15 textboxes, but only care that 4 of them are not empty, this is what I do for the check. I don't do this for every textbox as it is not needed

Comment: do you know the id's of your textboxes which you need to validate?

Comment: that is issue 1: they go from id="txtb1 to 15" and id 1,2,4,8 are the ones I am after. but if I change 1,2,4,8 to 1-4, then I could do a `for txtb1 to txt4 bla bla next txtb` or something like that.

Comment: so which one 4 out of those 15 you want to check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add unique `CssClass` to all 4 `TestBox`.
2. Find the parent control which holds all 4 `TextBox`.
3. And then try the following code.

If you have applied `validateempty` as `CssClass` for `TextBox` and if `Ctrl1` is the parent control which holds the textboxes then.

```
For Each ctrl as Control In Ctrl1.Controls
 Dim txt as TextBox = TryCast(ctrl, TextBox)
 If txt IsNot Nothing And txt.CssClass = "validateempty" And txt.Text.Trim() = "" Then 
  'Your choice of code hear.
 End If

Next
```

Using JQuery you can find an element by its `cssclass` name.
First add the JQuery reference to your page [You can find it hear](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_install.asp).
Second add the following function to `OnClientClick` attribute of the `submit button`.

```
function validate(){
//Since you have added cssclass for the textboxes as "validateempty" then
 var ret = true;
 $.find(".validateempty").each(function(){
 if(ret){
  if($(this).val().trim() == ""){
   alert("Enter the value.");
   $(this).focus();
   ret = false;
  }
 }
 });
return ret;
}
```

[`$.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) will find all elements with the provided filter parameter. In this case css class. If there are more than one value is returned as there are 4 text boxes, then loop through the result and check individual found element which can be found in $(this) element. If you specify `return` directly inside the `$.find()`, then it will return from the loop not from `function`.

Comment: isn't that same as having ids of those 4 textboxes and just check for them?

Comment: If any extra textbox is needed to be validated then you can just add cssclass and there is no need of code change.

Comment: OP wants the validation to be done on server side. If it's Client Side then it's not necessary to do it server at all. Using Java Script will be enough.

Comment: Bharadwaj, thanks I will try that, but client side would be better but I have to also, in the same submit click, do the sql insert, (if all fields I am after are not empty), so I really don't know which would be better.

Comment: @Sunny Thats right. For required field validation client side validation is the best approach, using javascript or JQuery. But `d4d4u1` wants it on server side.

Comment: @d4d4u1 As I commented before, for required field validation use client side approach, you can call both `javascript` function and serverside method on same button click. First the `javascript` function will be executed and then server method.

Comment: @Bharadwaj ok, how? that I do not know how to do both in one click, and get the error catch to exit out and return to the user. That and I do not know jscript or jquery that well. But I can read code, and follow it once I see it.

Comment: @Bharadwaj - ok, I must be missing something. I added the CssClass to the css file and to the txtboxes got the jquery downloaded and added it to the head section of master page. took the code from the script above and added it to the local content.head section of the local page. but nothing seems to be working right for me today. in the css I have `ctrl1.validateempty {}` on the page I have `<ctrl1><asp:textbox id="bla" cssclass="validateempty" /></ctrl1>` and the `onclientclick` in the submit button. I really am having a problem seeing where my mistake is.

Comment: @d4d4u1 In submit button you have to add `OnClientClick = "return validate();"`.

Answer (score 0):

You can maintain an array of Id's you want to validate.

```
   String[] txtboxToValidate = { "txtb1", "txtb2", "txtb4", "txtb8" };

    foreach (Control c in Page.Controls)
    {
        if (c is TextBox)
        {
            int pos = Array.IndexOf(txtboxToValidate, c.ID);
            TextBox txtBox = (TextBox)c;
            if (pos > -1)
            {
                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtBox.Text))
                {
                    //Write your logic how you want to throw your error.
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

It's in c# but logic remains same. You can convert it to VB using online code converters etc.

Comment: @Bharadwaj - Open google and type - c# to vb.net . hit enter :)

Comment: I can hit enter, but can questioner hit the same ;)

Comment: Thats fine I can convert it to VB, I can write in c# and VB, and yes I can press enter also. thats the key above the "Q" right? ;-}