# Alert on button click

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, .net, alert

I have four textboxes and I need to check for null values. If any of the textbox value has null values then on button click I need to show a alert like 'Please enter values'.

This code will disable if textbox value is empty.

**ASPX:**

```
<tr style="height: 40px;">
        <td>
            <asp:textbox id="txt1" runat="server">
            </asp:textbox>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:textbox id="txt2" runat="server">
            </asp:textbox>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:textbox id="txt3" runat="server">
            </asp:textbox>
        </td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
<asp:button id="Button1" runat="server" text="Add" cssclass="button" width="50px"
onclick="Button1_Click" /></td>
</tr>
```

**CS:**

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txt1.Text) || String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txt2.Text) || String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txt3.Text))
    {
        string message = "Textbox can be empty, please enter a value";
        string script = String.Format("alert('{0}');", message);
        this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page.GetType(), "msgbox", script, true);
    }

    if (txt1.Text != "" && txt2.Text != "" && txt3.Text != "" && ddlcategory.Text != "--Select--")
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(str))
        {
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
            command.Connection = connection;
            string strquery = "select * from product where code='Metal' and Id='" + txt1.Text + "'";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strquery, connection);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(ds);
        }
        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
             ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),"Key", "<script type='text/javascript'>window.onload = function(){alert('Product Already Exists.');return false;}</script>");                        
        }
        else
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(str);
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Products", conn);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.VarChar, 30).Value = txt1.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = txt2.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@email", SqlDbType.VarChar, 30).Value = txt3.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@category", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20).Value = ddlcategory.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 1;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
            conn.Dispose();
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Key", "<script type='text/javascript'>window.onload = function(){alert('Product Created Successfully.');return false;}</script>");               
        }
    }              
}
```

Anyone suggest me on this.

Comment: You can't do this server side, you have to use client side code.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Why can't server side?

Comment: OK, not "can't" but "better not". Server side means you make a full page reload while you can detect empty values before the form submission itself. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22221010/447356) that's what I mean.

Comment: I think you can get answer  here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22109986/check-if-certain-textboxes-are-empty/22110166

Comment: Yes! You can, have a look on link http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/722385/Single-Server-Side-Validator-for-Multiple-Controls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try below

```
if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txt1.Text) || String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txt2.Text) || String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txt3.Text) || String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txt4.Text))
{
    string message = "Please enter values";
    string script = String.Format("alert('{0}');", message);
    this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page.GetType(), "msgbox", script, true);
    return;
}
```

Comment: Damith - How can I validate whitespaces in this code? Means when I press space key inside the textbox and click the button I need to validate. Just because the textbox will only have white spaces.

Comment: Damith - The alert comes perfectly, but when I click ok in the alert box the item gets added.

Comment: which items you talking about?

Comment: I have updated my code for better clarity. Please take a look.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in client side with JavaScript code

```
function verifyValues()
{
    var txtBox1,txtBox2,txtBox3,txtBox4;
    txtBox1=document.getElementByID("<%= myTextBox1.ClientID %>"):
    txtBox2=document.getElementByID("<%= myTextBox2.ClientID %>"):
    txtBox3=document.getElementByID("<%= myTextBox3.ClientID %>"):
    txtBox4=document.getElementByID("<%= myTextBox4.ClientID %>"):

    if(txtBox1.value=="" || txtBox2.value==""||txtBox3.value=="" 
                         || txtBox4.value=="")
     {
      alert("Please enter any one of the value");
      return false;
     }
    return true;
}
```

Then your server side Markup should call javascript function with `return` statement

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" OnClientClick="return verifyValues();" 
       Text="Click" />
```

If you want double check both client and server side, please include @Damith answer in server side validation

Comment: I used this script and the alert doesn't show up when I left the column empty and on button click I was able to add the request.

Comment: What you mean by `when I left the column empty and on button click I was able to add the request`?

Comment: sorry its a textbox. I didn't enter any values in the textbox and when I clicked on button, I DIDN'T GET ANY ALERT FOR NULL VALUES. I mean when I give whitespaces they get added and also I need to validate that.

Comment: @Vicky, please post the rendered HTML. or you asp.net code for text boxes.

Answer (score 0):

I would use **string.IsNullOrEmpty()** instead and do the below.

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt1.Text)) {
   ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.Page.GetType(), 
          "err_msg", 
          "alert('Please enter values!)');",
          true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this instead of your code, and should be add `return false` after alert message showed

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt1.Text) ||string.IsNullOrEmpty( txt2.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt3.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt4.Text))
    {
       string script = "<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert('Please enter values');</script>";
       ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "Alert", script);
       Button1.Enabled = false;
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        Button1.Enabled = true;
    }


}
```

or

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt1.Text) ||string.IsNullOrEmpty( txt2.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt3.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt4.Text))
        {
         string script = "alert('Please enter values');";
         ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "Alert", script, true);
           Button1.Enabled = false;
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            Button1.Enabled = true;
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This one

```
if (txt1.Text == "" || txt2.Text == "" || txt3.Text == "" || txt4.Text == "")
        {
           ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, typeof(Page), "scrip1", "alert('Enter All fields');", true);
        Button1.Enabled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            Button1.Enabled = true;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply Required Field Validation on all the Textboxes and provide Group Name for all textboxes and for button on click of which validation should work, group name should be same for all the textboxes and for button.

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what you are looking for: (Server side validation for multiple control)

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/722385/Single-Server-Side-Validator-for-Multiple-Controls

Answer (score 0):

you have to do this  validation at client side which gives u improved performance

as follow

```
function verifyValues()
{
    var txtBox1,txtBox2,txtBox3,txtBox4;
    txtBox1=document.getElementByID("txt2"):
    txtBox2=document.getElementByID("txt2"):
    txtBox3=document.getElementByID("txt2"):
    txtBox4=document.getElementByID("txt2"):

    if(txtBox1.value=="" || txtBox2.value==""||txtBox3.value=="" 
                         || txtBox4.value=="")
     {
      alert("Please enter any one of the value");
      return false;
     }
    return true;
}
```